# OpenVMS initialization of record types

Tags: initialization, fortran, fortran77, openvms

I have some legacy code that I am trying to improve... one approach I like to take is using structures to organize data rather than equivalence operations.... shudder.  This is on OpenVMS Fortran 6.4 which I understand to be Fortran77 plus some stuff (might be wrong).

I want to initialize a record variable like so:

```
structure /my_data/
  integer*2   var1
  integer*2   var2
  character*5 NameTag
end structure

record /my_data/ OrganizedData

data OrganizedData /1, 2, 'Fred '/
```

I know the data statement is an error, the compiler told me so.  Checking in the help files, it appears that DATA does not support record variables in this version.  Can anyone confirm?  Any suggestions to initialize something like this other than direct assignments?

Comment: You want to use OpenVMS Fortran 6.4 for compilation?

Comment: yes, it's what I'm stuck with....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only the Oracle (Sun) manual here, not from OpenVMS, but it implements the same VAX extension (completely non-standard!). There is no structure constructor described there, that you could use for creating values of structure in single expression.

It also says:

> Record fields are not allowed in COMMON statements.
>
> Records and record fields are not allowed in DATA,EQUIVALENCE, or NAMELISTstatements.
>
> Record fields are not allowed in SAVE statement.

If you can use a compiler which accepts Fortran 90 you could use

```
type my_data
  integer*2   var1
  integer*2   var2
  character*5 NameTag
end type

type(my_data) :: OrganizedData

OrganizedData  = my_data(1, 2, 'Fred')
```

(I left the also non-standard * notation there.)

Comment: With this approach, you can also setup default initializations in the type declaration.

Comment: Right, in Fortran 95 and above.

Comment: of course now you need to go through all the code and change the `.` syntax to `%`. Worth the trouble? depends on how much code and how long you expect to need to maintain it.

Comment: Some compilers will allow you to stay with `.`, until you are comfortable to change the rest. At least `ifort` and Oracle `sunf90` will do. It is ugly, but `structure` is uglier.

Comment: Well, since I'm stuck with the old compiler, you've just confirmed what I've read.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in DEC Fortran:

```
structure /my_data/
  integer*2   var1 /1/
  integer*2   var2 /2/
  character*5 NameTag /'Fred'/
end structure

record /my_data/ OrganizedData

end
```

Note that the initializations are on the type - this will give the same initial values for all variables of that type.

Comment: Steve - goodness, I remember you from back in the early 90s while working at DEC.  I don't like your answer as OrganizedData is going to an array.  I'll figure out another way.

Comment: If you were using DEC Fortran 90 for OpenVMS, you'd have other options. It sounds as if you're using VAX FORTRAN-77, and not even the latest version of that. Given that, run-time initialization would be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

For that version of DEC FORTRAN, if you want different values for each instance, I think you need to initialize the record fields at run time.

```
 OrganizedData.var1 = 1 ! etc.
```

There are tricks, like using a COMMON and making a MACRO Assembler PSECT that initializes the values at compile time, but I'm guessing that's not what you are looking for. (Let me know if you are).

Also, I forget if it's 6.4 or not, but receiving a passed argument that has static initialization would cause a compiler error or warning.